# after azure failover, cannot RDP to VM nor change the recovery point in azure site recovery

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp, failover, azure-site-recovery

Is anyone here to help me out with my issues after performing azure to azure site recovery?

(1)I have performed test failover (using Azure site recovery) yesterday and done RDP successfully. Everything went fine.But today, when I did the actual Failover of VM, I cannot do RDP. I get the below error while connecting to RDP: ( I can't add image here, hence adding the message of the error)
Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:
1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network
Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.
*https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmqjL.png*﻿

Remote access is enabled via NSG, I see the remote computer on and running fine, but bit doubt on the network on which the VM is available as I see the network symbol with yellow triangle mark in the boot diagnosis image. How to solve this issue?

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHMHE.jpg*

﻿(2)I tried changing recovery point, but it failed. now I cannot do commit or fail back. Badly stuck in a worst situation. Didn't expect this situation with Azure live failover. All the options are faded. Please suggest what can be done here??? Received error as policy disallowed, policy name  "Allowed virtual machine SKU's"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very unfortunate! And the error message also seems like just a very generic one.
My default go-to questions for these things is usually:
1) did you try the generic network test? ping, tracert, nslookup -> If network connectivity does not exist then at least ping and tracert should give you errors. Otherwise DNS could be your issue.
2) When you lookup the VM in the portal it has this re-deploy option in the blade. It re-deploys the guest VM to a different host in the rack, for whatever faulty hardware it might be running on.
3) If network and hardware is not the issue, it could be the OS which is not responding to the RDP request the host receives. Reboot should fix that, or if it got corrupted somehow: Try recovering the OS disk and swap it into the VM.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. yes, the issue is with the DNS, hence the RDP issue.

Comment: Would like to share the solution here so that it would be helpful to those who stuck with the same issue:
1. There is no connectivity to the VM from on-premise machines and We have provided DNS servers as on-premise servers. We created a connection between VM network and on-premise network and then the issue got solved.
2. We disabled the policy for an instance and re-run the job. The job got success.